# No preset version installed for command yarn

Tags: node.js, zsh, apple-m1, asdf, yarn-lock.json

I have problem with asdf.
I have already install nodejs latest.

```
asdf install nodejs latest
... 
asdf local nodejs latest / asdf global nodejs latest
```

But if I try

```
yarn                                                         
No preset version installed for command yarn
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install nodejs 18.0.0

or add one of the following versions in your config file at /Users/../project-name/.tool-versions
nodejs 14.17.0
nodejs 19.0.1
```

But my .tool-version in project structure already contains it:

```
nodejs 18.0.0
nodejs 19.0.1
```

(For my project I need nodejs >= 18)
I am using apple M1 chip.

Comment: The error message asdf gives for this is atrocious.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This happens when you have yarn installed under a different version of node, but not the active one. As yarn is a package under the node version, so you need to (re)install yarn with the new active version of node:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Then it should work.

Comment: After this npm install succeeded, also needed `asdf reshim nodejs 16.19.1` (or your target version). Then `yarn` finally worked! Thank you Wil.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the local instance for asdf, using
`asdf local nodejs 19.0.1`